# Android Emulator Nexus_5_API_24 in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1 asks for a password

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-emulator

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1 and when I start Android Emulator Nexus_5_API_24, it asks for a password.

It can accept `'12345'`, but nothing happens:

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong, please?